# Is the CKEditor module compatible with the Picture and Breakpoint modules?

Tags: wysiwyg, theming, media

Is CKEditor (7.x-1.16 with library 4.4.3) compatible with the Picture (7.x-2.11) and Breakpoints (7.x-1.3) modules?

I have read numerous articles which say that they are and suggest configurations but also some forum post indicating that they are not.

Viewing the source of CKEitor after inserting an image and specifying "Image size":

```
<p class="rtecenter"><img alt="Made in heaven" data-picture-align="center" data-picture-mapping="omega_ful" src="/i/made-in-heaven.png" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px"></p>
```

Viewing the markup on a page created using CKEditor:

```
<p class="rtecenter"><img alt="Made in heaven" data-picture-align="center" data-picture-mapping="omega_ful" src="/i/made-in-heaven.png" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px"></p>
```

It is identical to the CKEditor source.

**Is anyone able to confirm, from first hand experience, if the 3 modules can work together to produce responsive/adaptive images?**

Configuration Info:
In /admin/config/content/formats/full_html:
"Make images responsive with the picture module" is selected.
Filter processing order is:

- Convert URLs into links
- Convert line breaks into HTML
- Make images responsive with the picture module
- Correct faulty and chopped off HTML
  (the same markup is produced even if only "Make images responsive with the picture module" is selected)

In /admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full > EDITOR APPEARANCE:
"Support responsive images with the Picture module." is selected.

Update: It does work sometimes, under certain conditions, but not all. Trying to figure out why it works sometimes but not others....

Comment: Cannot answer your question, but it is worth noting that CKEditor module seems to be experiencing a serious lack of maintenance. Lots of bugs that have not been fixed. I have a patch waiting in the issue queue to fix a crucial bug with CKEditor in how it is handling file access. It is a bug that is affecting a module I maintain. The alternative is to use WYSIWYG module and use the latest CKEditor library.

Comment: @Brady it is true that there are lots of uncommitted patches for CKEditor but there is also for WYSIWYG. In fact it actually has more uncommitted RTBC patches than CKEditor. Also with WYSIWYG you are pretty much forced to use the latest dev because there hasn't been a stable release in almost 3 years and only dev supports recent versions of editors. So I wouldn't necessarily use lack of support as a reason to switch.

Comment: @rooby True but at least with WYSIWYG the changes are in the repo and you can use the dev branch. As a module developer, you quickly learn "stable release" on D.O is an arbitrary term.

Comment: Both modules have changes in the repo and both modules are similarly maintained in that they have a similar number of commits since the start of this year and they have a similar number of patches in "Needs review" and "RTBC" statuses. In this case where maintenance status is actually very similar I don't think it's a good reason to switch from one to the other. Sure you can use the dev version but not many people do, check the usage stats for wysiwyg. That's a lot of users on a very outdated version. Not having a release in that long due to unfinished issues is relevant to maintenance.

Comment: @Taylor: I have not yet tried but a quick look at the code of the picture modules indicates that the way it works is that CKEditor creates markup like that you have posted and then a Drupal input filter runs on it and converts it to the expected picture tag output. Are you looking at the markup in the text area with WYSIWYG disabled or when viewing the saved content? Have you configured your text format to use the "Make images responsive with the picture module" filter?

Comment: @rooby, I have just added some config to the question, can add more if you think helpful, just let me know what.

Comment: I've tested with WYSIWYG + CKEditor before, it changes and overrides the default CKEditor image upload button to include a picture mapping select box. The result does output correct responsive picture element. I think you needed to use the WYSIWYG dev version though, and use version 4 CKEditor. I can't remember too well but I remember having needed to upgrade CKeditor to version 4 to get the button working correctly.